# Ansible: Archive module does not take into account exclude_path param

Tags: ansible

I want to archive the following directory:

```
temp_build_directory: /tmp/mdr-upgrade
```

Where

```
$ ls -1 /tmp/mdr-upgrade
ansible
atr
composefiles
data
images
packs
wheelhouse
```

and the task is:

```
- name: archive_artifacts.yml --> Archive artifacts
    archive:
      path: "{{ temp_build_directory }}/*"
      dest: "{{ target_tmp_dir }}/{{ artifacts_file_name }}"
      exclude_path: "{{ target_tmp_dir }}/{{ ansible_dir }}"
```

And `ansible_dir: ansible`

Tarball ends up always containing the `ansible` folder.

Why is that?

**edit**: I am using `target_tmp_dir: "/tmp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude_path` needs an absolute path (see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/archive_module.html#parameters)).
Try again with:

```
- name: archive_artifacts.yml --> Archive artifacts
    archive:
      path: "{{ temp_build_directory }}/*"
      dest: "{{ target_tmp_dir }}/{{ artifacts_file_name }}"
      exclude_path: "{{ temp_build_directory }}/{{ ansible_dir }}"
```

Comment: yes, but not the correct path as I see: `temp_build_directory: /tmp/mdr-upgrade`

Comment: yep it was just a typo...thx for taking the time to point this out...accepted/upvoted;